# How to Re-render a specific Component in react when a Property changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an App in which I want for a specific button to rerender the `Chart` component. This chart component has an animation I want to fire when my button is called

```
import './App.css';
import Charts from './Charts/Charts'
import LeftSideBar from './LeftSideBar/LeftSideBar'
import RightSideBar from './RightSideBar/RightSideBar'
import {useState} from 'react'
import DateContext from './context/DateContext'

function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [result,setResult] = useState(16)
  if (result > 41 ){
    setResult(0)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">

        <DateContext.Provider value={{startDate:startDate,endDate:endDate,result:result}}>
                    <LeftSideBar />
                    <Charts/>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <RightSideBar 
                    setStartDate={setStartDate} 
                    setEndDate={setEndDate} 
                    setResult={setResult}
                    />
        </DateContext.Provider>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is my `DatePicker` in which my logic resides, I want this button to rerender my `Chart` component when called

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import '../style.css'
import DateContext from "../context/DateContext";

const Datepicker = (props) => {
    const {setStartDate, setEndDate, setResult} = props
    const {startDate,endDate} = useContext(DateContext)
    const handleCalculation = () =>{
        let substractedTime = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()
        let substractedDays = substractedTime/ (1000 * 3600 * 24)
        setResult(Math.floor(substractedDays/7))
    }
    return (
    <>
    <h6>DATE DES DERNIERES REGLES</h6>
       <div className="picker1"><DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} /></div>
    <h6>DATE DE LA CONSULTATION</h6>
      <div className="picker2"><DatePicker selected={endDate} onChange={date => setEndDate(date)} /> 
      </div>
      <button className='btn submit' onClick={()=>{handleCalculation()}}>Calculer</button>
    </>
    );
  };

export default Datepicker
```

Comment: If the button calls `handleCalculation` which calls `setResult` callback which updates `result` state in `App`, then `App` should rerender which will trigger a rerender of all children, including `Charts`. `Charts` doesn't consume any props. Can you include the `Charts` component code so we may see why it may not be rerendering with (*presumably*) some update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in **"React"** you should use a conditional setState inside **"useEffect"**. So, as per your code you should replace this code:

```
if (result > 41 ){
  setResult(0)
}
```

With:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (result > 41 ){
    setResult(0)
  }
},[result])
```

And in case of your **rerendering** issue, As per your given code, the **"handleCalculation()"** function is called when the button is clicked. And the **"handleCalculation()"** function calls **"setResult()"**. So, according to the functionality of **React** , your **"App"** component should re-render. So, in that case there is nothing wrong in your code. There might be some issue in the **"Charts"** component.

You may also check whether the re-render is happening or not using a **"console.log"** just before the **"return()"** statement. Like:

```
function App() {
  ...your code...

  console.log("Rendered");

  return (
    ...your code...
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't console log in the body of a functional component, this is considered an unintentional side-effect, i.e. it would console log during the "render phase" when React may render the component to compute any DOM differences. This should not be confused with the "commit phase" when changes to React's virtual DOM are committed and pushed to the DOM and where component lifecycle functions are called, i.e. `useEffect`. If you want to check when a component truly rerenders then this also should be done in an `useEffect` hook.